# If in a matrix I add rows to each other, does its spectral radius change?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, spectral-radius

In the context of the Jacobi method, we have Ax=b and I need to add rows to have the entire diagonal of A with non-zero elements and be able to calculate the matrix D^(-1)(L+U). My question is, will the way I choose to reorder or add the rows change the convergence of the method? Jacobi's method converges if the spectral radius is less than 1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, it can change.